# concatMap is getting called only once when used along with switchMap

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

**pre-info:**

**`dishService.query`**: returns an `Observable`, a list of dishes; Each dish has `lat`, `lng` properties

**`geoLocationService.getDistanceFromLatLng$`**: returns an `Observable`, distance when passed: `lat`, `lng` coords;

**code:**

```
this.pageSubject.pipe(
  switchMap((filter: DishFilter)=>this.dishService.query(filter)),//gets a list of dishes
  tap(_=>console.log("after switchmap", _)
  concatMap(page=>combineLatest(page.results.map(dish=>
        this.geoLocationService.getDistanceFromLatLng$({lat:  user.current_location.lat, lng:  user.current_location.lng}, {lat: dish.restaurant_lat, lng: dish.restaurant_lng}).pipe(
          map(distance=>dish.distance = distance),
          tap(_=>console.log("after distance", _))
        )
      )
    ), (page, results) => {
        return page
    }
  ),//for each dish attach a  distance property using geoLocationService.getDistanceFromLatLng$;Observable
  tap(=>console.log("after concatmap")),
).subscribe((page: Page)=>{
  //use page somewhere
  console.log("completed")
  this.cdRef.detectChanges();
});
```

The I did:

```
this.pageSubject.next(filter);//logs to console: after switchmap, after distance..., after concatmap, completed
this.pageSubject.next(filter);//logs to console: after switchmap
```

In the second call to `pageSubject.next(filter)`, the concatMap doesn't execute. Why?

Comment: `combineLatest` requires all source Observables to emit at least once, so are you sure all `this.geoLocationService.getDistanceFromLatLng$` emit at least once?

Comment: Do `this.dishService.query` use `HttpClient` or `Subject`?

Comment: It uses `HttpClient`

Comment: @martin If thats the case, any alternative to `combineLatest` which emits even if one of them=> `this.geoLocationService.getDistanceFromLatLng$` doesn't emit after a certain time?

Comment: @martin, I don't think `this.geoLocationService.getDistanceFromLatLng$` is emitting. Not even once. In the network tab, I don't see any requests being made. That means the `concatMap` or `combineLatest` are not executing at all.

Comment: You can use `startWith(null)` for each source to be sure they emit at least once. `this.geoLocationService.getDistanceFromLatLng$.pipe(startWith(null))`

Comment: @martin Now I see weird behavior, the subscribe is executing 10 times for 10 dishes returned via `dishService.query`, when I used `startWith(null)`; which used to execute only once. And again, that didn't solve the issue. Though the execution is completing, all results include `null` in `distance`  property of `Dish` for the second `pageSubject.next(filter)`.

Comment: Is it possible there's an error that you're not logging? In the call to subscribe, pass error and complete handlers and log what's happening there